# Перевести код с использованием классов

Tags: javascript, ооп, рефакторинг

Помогите переделать этот код с использованием классов и конструкторов для инициализации объектов классов.

```
function Persona(first, last, day, month, year) {
    this.name = {
        first,
        last
    };
    this.Birthday = {
        day,
        month,
        year
    };
};

var person1 = new Persona('Name', 'Surname', 11, 11, 1111);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы про это имели ввиду?

```js
class Persona{

  constructor(first, last, day, month, year) {
    this.name = {
      first,
      last
    };
    this.Birthday = {
      day,
      month,
      year
    };
  }
  
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`;
  }
}

var person1 = new Persona('Name', 'Surname', 11, 11, 1111);
console.log(person1.fullName);
```

Comment: да, спасибо большое